# How do I run Octave from a different directory?

Tags: bash

I have recently installed Octave, a MATLAB clone, onto the following directory:

```
/Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin/octave
```

I want to run it from a shell command prompt from a different directory, say, from my home directory ~.  I know that I can type the full path to the octave executable, but that is very cumbersome.  I know that on linux computers you can edit your .bashrc file to include paths to special directories with executables.  How do I accomplish that here in Mac OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your .bashrc (or .bash_profile, .login, etc.) on a Mac, and add the line

```
alias octave='/Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin/octave'
```

Comment: In linux computers, aliases don't pass into shell scripts.  This is why we export paths to the bashrc file.  I imagine mac computers have the same problem.  Is there a way to include this path for later use in shell scripts?

Comment: In linux computers, and OS X, login scripts (.bashrc, .bash_profile) are treated differently by user login (interactive shell) versus script. Put the alias in the appropriate place (linux or OS X) and your shell scripts **will** have access to the alias. I think .bashrc is interactive only, and .bash_profile is accessed by shell scripts.

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man